# Page moves to top of screen when sorting items

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating an sortable portfolio with jQuery.

The problem is; every time I click on an filter of my portfolio items, then the page scrolls to the top.

Is there an way to prevent that?

Can see the problem here: http://alsite.com.br/flex/produtos.html

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Portfolio = {
            sort: function(items) {
                items.show();
                $('#portfolio-content').find('div.portfolio-item').not(items).fadeOut(500);
            },
            showAll: function(items) {
                items.fadeIn(500);
            },
            doSort: function() {
                $('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function() {

                    var $a = $(this);
                    if (!$a.is('#all')) {

                        var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');

                        Portfolio.sort(items);

                    } else {

                        Portfolio.showAll($('div.portfolio-item', '#portfolio-content'));


                    }

                });
            }
        };

        Portfolio.doSort();     

    });

</script>
```

my portfolio code:

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div id="portfolio-sort">
        <a href="#" id="all">TODOS</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="a">ACM</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="b">MDF</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="c">AÇO INOX</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="b">PVC ESPANDIDO</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="c">AÇO GALVANIZADO</a>

    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-content">
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change:

```
$('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function() { ...
```

To:

```
$('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function(e) { ...
```

And add:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

--

```
$('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function() {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...
});
```

--

This prevents the link from functioning as a link (and taking you to `produtos.html#`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the link from being an link :)

```
$('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function(e) {
    // stop being an link!
    e.preventDefault();

    var $a = $(this);

    if (!$a.is('#all')) {
        var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');

        Portfolio.sort(items);
    } else {
        Portfolio.showAll($('div.portfolio-item', '#portfolio-content'));
    }
});
```

More info: [click](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: thankz too for the edit review of my question. My english is so bad!